# Most Efficient Way to Remove Objects With Null Attributes From a List

Tags: java, performance, list, loops, collections

So I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this in java? Assuming the list of objects is currently populated...

```
for (Object obj : objects) {
   if (obj.getAttribute() == null) {
      objects.remove(obj);
   }
}
```

Essentially, I just want to be able to remove any objects from a given list if objects in that list contain a specific null attribute. Thoughts?

Comment: You cannot remove objects the way you've written the code without the possibility of introducing a ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java 8:

```
objects.removeIf(o -> o.getAttribute() == null);
```

In prior versions:

```
for (Iterator<MyObject> it = objects.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if (it.next().getAttribute() == null)
        it.remove();
}
```

Also see [Removing items from a collection in java while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675037/removing-items-from-a-collection-in-java-while-iterating-over-it). (The `for` loop as you've shown can throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.)

Both of these *are* more *efficient* because they allow the collection to do the iteration and removal in the way that they want to, but I don't think it's *particularly* important here unless you have a giant collection and do this a lot.

As an example of how these could be better, the code the question shows has poor time complexity for a linked list (something like `O(n2/2)` for a worst case, I think) because the call to `objects.remove` requires another traversal. Using an `Iterator` lets the list do the removal without traversing.

Using an `Iterator` is still poor for an `ArrayList`, though, because the elements get shifted every time. The Java 8 version is the best. [`ArrayList` uses a `BitSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.removeIf%28java.util.function.Predicate%29) and does the shifting all at once.

Comment: Ah, didn't even think about that exception being thrown. And unfortunately I'm working in an environment in which we don't currently use Java 8, so the latter option using the iterator is the one I must go with. But I'll keep that `removeIf` in the back of my mind in case we do decide to upgrade our java version here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Iterators are pretty ugly. : )